# Magento2: How to display out of stock product in wishlist

Tags: magento2.2, php-7.2

How to display out of stock products only in the wishlist.

How to do that.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

kindly follow this hope it is helpfull if any issues let me know https://www.magestore.com/magento-2-tutorial/magento-2-displaydisable-out-of-stock-product-by-your-own/

Comment: Works Fine Thank you @mohith